# Why use local require in Lua?

Tags: lua, require, local-variables

What's the difference between this

```
local audio = require "audio"
```

and

```
require "audio"
```

Is there any advantage of the former?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Lua a module is an object that exports several public functions. There are two ways of defining a module in Lua. For instance:

```
module(..., package.seeall)

Audio = {}

function Audio:play()
   print("play")
end
```

Or alternatively:

```
Audio = {}

function Audio:play()
   print("play")
end

return Audio
```

The former is the old way of defining a module, but it's still can be found in many examples. The latter is the preferred way of defining modules now.

So, unless you assign a module to a local variable there's no way of referencing its exported variables and methods.

If `audio` had defined any global functions, those functions would be available once `audio` is imported. Global functions and variables are attached to the global object. In Lua there's a variable called _G which contains all global variables and functions defined. For instance,

**audio.lua**

```
function play()
   print("play")
end
```

**main.lua**

```
require("audio")

play()
```

Or

```
require("audio")

_G.play()
```

That works, but putting everything in the global object has several inconveniences. Variables and functions may be overwritten. Eventually the global object becomes and bloated. It's better to structure everything in modules, so variables and methods are encapsulated in their own namespace.

Comment: It is common to use `local Audio = {}` and let the client decide whether to save it as a global.

Comment: So the main reason is to prevent the imported file clobbering the global namespace. And I guess another benefit is avoiding name conflicts.